# How do I recalculate UICollectionViewFlowLayout on orientation change?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

In portrait, all my CollectionViewCells are aligned properly.

[image]

When switched to Landscape the cells are now spaced out more.

[image]

What would be the proper way to recalculate `UICollectionViewFlowLayout's` `minimumInterimSpacing` and `itemSize` on orientation changes? I'd like to display 6 columns in landscape.

Comment: Do you want to change the item Size and/or itemSize for each cell?

Comment: @SyedeHussaini I want to change the itemSize for each cell so I can fit 6 cells in landscape view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this logic to change your cell size and spacing with respect to your device orientation.

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator{
    //create two properties for storing a bool and sizeOfYourScreen
    //In your viewDidLoad method initialize both of these object with NO and self.view.frame.size
    //get your Portrait screen size
    if (portraitScreenSize > size.height) {
        self.isPortrate = NO;
    }else{
        self.isPortrate = YES;
    }
    self.size = size;
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.isPortrate) {

        //Calculate your interitemSpacing with respect to size and then simply return it
        return newInteritemSpacing;
    }else{
        //Calculate your interitemSpacing with respect to size and then simply return it
        return newInteritemSpacing;
    }

}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.isPortrate) {

        //Calculate your lineSpacing with respect to size and then simply return it
        return newlineSpacing;
    }else{
        //Calculate your interitemSpacing with respect to size and then simply return it
        return newlineSpacing;
    }
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Here you should return your size of each item
    if (self.isPortrate) {

        //Calculate your lineSpacing with respect to size and then simply return it
        return sizeOfCellInPortrate;
    }else{
        //Calculate your interitemSpacing with respect to size and then simply return it
        return sizeOfCellInLandscape;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Since Syed e Hussaini already given the correct answer I'll just leave mine here for anyone that needs it in Swift.**

You need to conform to UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout in your view controller, and then use its methods `sizeForItemAt()` and `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt()` to determine the size and spacing, and then use `viewWillTransitionToSize()` to detect orientation change.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    // Reloads collection view
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        // Returns size for cell when in landscape
    } else {
        // Returns size for cell when NOT in landscape
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        // Returns spacing for cells when in landscape
    } else {
        // Returns spacing for cells when NOT in landscape
    }
}
```

Comment: Swift 4 API change for the transition callback: func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)

Comment: Thanks @MartinWestin. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Don't forget the call to super for viewWillTransition(to...